# "Invalid or missing alias DNS TXT records." when using associate-alias, even though the record appears to exist

Tags: dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I'm trying to transfer an alternate domain name from one Cloudfront distribution to another, following the instructions on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-move

When I run the following command: `aws cloudfront associate-alias --alias dev.example.net --target-distribution-id E37***********` it gives the error message `An error occurred (IllegalUpdate) when calling the AssociateAlias operation: Invalid or missing alias DNS TXT records.`

I have added the DNS TXT record and waited for it to report `INSYNC` in the console.

The subdomain I am trying to transfer is `dev.example.net` and as per the doc, I've added a TXT record for `_dev.example.net`. I have done this by adding a record to our `example.net` hosted zone with the subdomain `_dev`.

Here's how the record appears in Route 53 console:
[Route 53 record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjCBn.png)

Performing `nslookup -q=TXT _dev.example.net` gives the following:

```
Server:  ip-***-**-*-*.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
Address:  ***.**.*.*

Non-authoritative answer:
_dev.example.net  text =

        "d*************.cloudfront.net"
```

If it helps, *before* I added that TXT record, `nslookup -q=TXT _dev.example.net` gave the following response:

```
Server:  ip-***-**-*-*.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
Address:  ***.**.*.*

example.net
        primary name server = ns-1536.awsdns-00.co.uk
        responsible mail addr = awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com
        serial  = 1
        refresh = 7200 (2 hours)
        retry   = 900 (15 mins)
        expire  = 1209600 (14 days)
        default TTL = 86400 (1 day)
```

Other info:

- My target distribution has a certificate for `dev.example.net` associated with it
- `example.net` is a placeholder for my actual root domain throughout
- I have permission to update both distributions and perform the associate-alias operation
- Both distributions are in the same account
- I've also tried putting the TXT record under `dev.` rather than `_dev.`
- I've also tried putting the TXT record under `_.dev.` (as per some Japanese article I found)
- Potentially important: I have **not** pointed `dev.example.net` to my target distribution in Route 53 yet. In the docs it indicates that that should be done after running the associate-alias command successfully.
- Potentially important: the hosted zone I am using is Private

Comment: What about an apex domain, like example.com? I tried to add _.example.com, but it wouldn't work. I get the same IllegalUpdate error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the private hosted zone causing problems.
For me, the solution was to use our public production `example.net` hosted zone and create `_dev.example.net TXT d******.cloudfront.net` there.